# how do I format text in swagger-api ApiOperation notes section

Tags: java, swagger

How do I add a list in swagger-api notes section for an end point?
something like this

```
  List of supported filters are
       1. list of performers only
       2. list list of activities only                 
       3. active/inactive flag in combination with performer
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far and what's not working?

Comment: I tried /br and /n, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

@ApiOperation notes accepts html tags.  But depending on which version of swagger you're using, it seems to be either a simple subset or buggy.  (E.g. I could not get  to create a numbered list in swagger 2.)

Either of these come pretty close:

```
@ApiOperation(
value="value",
notes="List of supported filters are<br>1. list of performers only<br>2. list list of activities only <br>3. active/inactive flag in combination with performer"
)
```

or

```
@ApiOperation(
value="value",
notes="List of supported filters are<ol><li>list of performers only</li><li>list list of activities only</li><li>active/inactive flag in combination with performer</li></ol>"
)
```